# SSH Server Connection over VPN

Tags: ssh, security, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I connect my VPS over SSH terminal via ssh keys stored in my computer, password login is disabled.

But sometimes I need to surf web behind VPN service which changes public IP for my home computer.

Because VPN IPs may be assigned for many users at a time, can another VPN user having same IP with me connect my VPS? Or may there be any other security issue for SSH connections over VPN?

Comment: Well as you said the password login is disabled on the server then I don't think that any one could login to the system without having the correct private key. Still to ensure more security you can use a non standard port for your ssh server or you can use service like **fail2ban** which will block most of the bruteforce attack on you server.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, to me also private keys will not allow for another person but I wanted to make sure I do not create any other security exploit this way.